# Stuck during calculations to show that $\mathbb{E}e^{uX}=e^{u\mu + 0.5u^2\sigma^2}$ for normal random variable $X$

Tags: normal-distribution, expectation

I am reading S. Shreve's introduction to Stochastic Calculus. Exercise 1.6. (p. 43) should be a simple exercise, but I don't know how to continue.

Let $u$ be a fixed number in $\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ a normal random variable with density

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$

I would like to show that $\mathbb{E}e^{uX}=e^{u\mu + 0.5u^2\sigma^2}$.

Since the density function is given, I can calculate

$$\mathbb{E}e^{uX}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ux}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2-2\sigma^2ux}{2\sigma^2}}dx.$$

But I don't see how to solve this integral.

What I have tried so far:

- find the antiderivative
- find a change of variables to change this integral back to a normal distribution.
- do I have to use Fubini's theorem and solve this slice by slice? Didn't manage to do this.

Could you please give me a hint on how to continue?

---

Edit: the main step is to complete the square inside the integral:

$\exp(-\frac{x^2-2x\mu -2\sigma^2 ux-\mu^2}{2\sigma^2})$

$=\exp (-\frac{(x-(\mu -\sigma^2u))^2}{2\sigma^2}) \cdot\exp(\frac{\mu^2-(\mu-\sigma^2u)^2}{2\sigma^2})$

The integral of the first exponent is 1 and the second exp gives the solution.

Comment: The integral should be $\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2 - 2\sigma^2 u x}{2 \sigma^2}} \, dx$.

Comment: @J.J. fixed, thanks.

Comment: "Since the density function is given, I can calculate $\displaystyle\mathbb{E}e^{uX}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty X(x)\mathbb{P}(x)dx$..." **Ouch!** The RHS hurts...

Comment: Same RHS still not correct, sorry.

Comment: @Did thanks for checking. One more try?

Comment: Correct now. Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Complete the square in the exponent and do a change of variables.

Comment: thanks! it seems I always run into problems due to sign errors :(